# How does cc_load_policy work in youtube iframe Player API to show subtitles?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to use the 'cc_load_policy' parameter of the youtube API-iframe player. And I'm not able to make it work on my page.

As you can see, I'm indicating the cc_load_policy to 1 so that the subtitles are always shown and the cc_lang pred to 'en' (Since my subtitles are in English).

```js
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: /*MY YOUTUBE ID*/,
        playlist: /*MY YOUTUBE ID */,
        playerVars:{
           'autoplay': 1,
           'controls': 0,
           'disablekb': 0,
           'fs':0,
           'modestbranding':0,
           'rel':0,
           'hd':1,
           'autohide': 0,
           'wmode': 'transparent',
           'showinfo': 0,
           'loop' : 1,
           'cc_load_policy' : 1,
           'cc_lang_pref' : 'en',
           'iv_load_policy' : 3
       },
       events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange' : onStateChange
       }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {event.target.playVideo();}
function onStateChange(evt){
   if (evt.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
       player.playVideo(); 
   }
}
```

If the url that general the code copied and pasted on a tab, the subtitles work perfectly, however within the iframe autogenerated by the api, it does not work.

Does anyone know what my mistake is? Can the Api have an error or an unknown limitation for me?

I have read the documentation several times and I can not find an explanation for my problem.

Comment: Can you share the `videoId` you're using? - I'm going to post an answer based on my findings...

Comment: My videoId is cpx2C13kAqw

Comment: Victor, check the jsfiddle that I added in my answer. It works as expected. Are you still having this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they have been useful.
I think the error comes because of the autoinicio issue, because if I do not launch that parameter and the mute works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you had set the `autoplay` value to `1` and, during my tests it seems that autoplay wont work if the video is not muted.

---

I did create this [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/obj6qa5t/) with your API settings and I can't say for sure if the problem is with your specific `videoId` but, one thing is certain: if you want autoplay your video, I think you need to set the value `mute` to `0` for make it work.

Also, would be useful if you check that the `videoId` you want use in your API settings has subtitles *(and in the language you intend to show)*.

The other change I made in your API settings was comment the `width` and `height` values - those values aren't the problem, though.

The used `videoId` in this sample is from the video:

> [Descubre a S4G Consulting con nuestro #S4GMood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpx2C13kAqw)

Here is the code - just that you wont see working this code here because Stack Overflow has certain restrictions for play YouTube videos...

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    /*height: '100%',
    width: '100%',*/
    videoId: 'cpx2C13kAqw',
    playlist: 'cpx2C13kAqw',
    playerVars: {
      'autoplay': 1,
      'mute': 1,
      'controls': 0,
      'disablekb': 0,
      'fs': 0,
      'modestbranding': 0,
      'rel': 0,
      'hd': 1,
      'autohide': 0,
      'wmode': 'transparent',
      'showinfo': 0,
      'loop': 1,
      'cc_load_policy': 1,
      'cc_lang_pref': 'en',
      'iv_load_policy': 3
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

function onStateChange(evt) {
  if (evt.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.playVideo();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```